# How to create eclipse java/maven launch config independent of eclipse project name?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, launch

All our special maven and java launch configs are under version control at `<project>/.launch`:

[image]

- now we are considering checking out our projects NOT into the eclipse workspace but another place
- and then just import the projects in eclipse (without copying contents)
- the "Import Maven Project" wizard lets you define a project template name:

[image]

The problem is then that the `Base directory` cannot be resolved anymore.
And I am also unsure if the `Shared file` location in the Common tab is still valid/functioning.

Any ideas how to allow developers to import projects with whatever project name template they want while still keeping the launch configs working?

Comment: What kind of launch configuration do you need to start Maven? Already integrated into Eclipse ? Can you more elaborate what you like to achieve?

Comment: Both java (special args and parameters) and maven (special plugins and goals).

Comment: For java apps I would prefer to make scripts and for Maven which kind of plugins and goals ? Do you need? Except: `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: Both developers and non-technical people in our team are already used to working with these launch configs. With this question I try to find ways to continue to support these, while loosening constraints on eclipse project names.